# Power BI - Weekly X-Axis without year, but still sorted chronologically

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

since I started to use Power BI for my weekly reports, I was not able to resolve the following issue.

Most of my charts are on a weekly basis, so for example a chart of the last 13 weeks will have the following weeks as x-axis values: 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7.

The problem in this case is, that if I sort it by week, Power BI will always sort the values like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52. This is obviously wrong because week 1 of the following year should be placed after week 52 of the previous year.

So I came to the following solution: I concatenated the year value with the week value, so the values look like this: ..., 202151, 202152, 202201, 202202, ...
This solved at least my sorting issue. The graphs are displayed in the correct chronological order.

But there is one problem with this solution: The six-digit values are just way to huge and it is very hard for the reader to differ between the weeks.

[too large markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIplw.png)

I would like to have only the 2-digit week number displayed on the x-axis, but still keep the sorting properly over the change of a year.

I hope someone has solved this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure YearWeek as the "[sort by column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column)" for WeekNumber, and switch the X-Axis type to "Categorical" on your Bar Chart

[image]
or Line Chart

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there has to be an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [small multiples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-small-multiples):

[image]

Rough steps:

1. Create a columns chart
2. In the *Axis* field place your week number column
3. In the *Values* field place your column containing the values
4. In the *Small multiples* field place the year column
5. Format your visual such that the *Small multiple grid* has 1 row, but multiple columns.